# vertical align is not working with divs

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've a copyright div at the bottom of the page in the middle containing a background image and text. I'm displaying this div as a table-cell with vertical-align:middle but the text displays at the topof the div not the bottom. Here's the page: http://www.mawk3y.net/ammar/rawt/

```
.copyright {
color: #000;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
width: 120px;
height: 61px;
text-align: center;
background: url('../images/footer_logo.png') no-repeat center top;
vertical-align: bottom;
display: table-cell;
float: left;
margin-top: 13px;
margin-left: 270px;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `table-cell` on a element that has `float: left;` on it. You would have to do a div inside that one with `table-cell`. I would just go with Roko C.Buljian answer with `padding`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a background image for your logo,
to display the text "below" it, assign

```
padding-top:50px;
```

to your *copyright* element. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. So i should remove the background image to make vertical-align work?

Comment: @Yasser the padding allows to keep the background covering the padding area, but keep the text in the non-padding area below. You can always use an `<img>` instead of the background.

Comment: I know about padding just found out that vertical-align didn't work and had to know why. Thanks for your help @Roko